# UML: How do I model classes that other programmers may use but not modify?

Tags: java, oop

I have a question in my assignment that asks for a UML design of a system

My assignment asks me to allow programmers to use this system but not modify its components (the classes involved) and also list relevant keywords I use for this as well.

How do I set up the classes so that this requirement is satisfied?

Comment: Use the class as a final one ...

Comment: What exactly do you want to prevent others from modifying?

Comment: The classes and methods belonging to them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conceptual answer in Java is to use the **final** keyword for those elements (classes, or methods within classes) that you want to prevent from being **overridden** in sub classes.

But that is on an "informal" level. Your classes are (in the end) distributed; thus you lose **ownership**. If somebody wants, he can take your source code, remove the **final** keyword and re-compile. Even, when you only distribute compiled class files, one can de-compile them, remove **final** and recompile.

But for students doing assignments, **final** is the way to go. Of course, the big downside of that is: **final** classes can give trouble to *mocking frameworks*, so that makes unit testing a bit more tricky. Thus you want to make sure that you have nice **interfaces** that people can implement on their own if they have to; and to make only your "impl" classes final.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think this is exactly what I needed

Comment: You are welcome. But for the record: try to figure such things yourself first. Learning means to do research yourself. Asking here is cheating ;-)

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, there's absolutely no way to prevent people from modifying your source code (at least from Java). There isn't really a way to model that in UML either. (If that's really what the assignment is asking for, I'm slightly baffled as to what they were driving at; is it possible you're misreading the assignment?)

Some version control systems *might* let you restrict who can edit certain files, but I've never tried to do that so I can't tell you much about that).

Another thing you can *definitely* do is monitor the file once it's in version control to keep tabs on who's modifying it - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41065258/how-to-find-all-changes-that-were-made-to-a-library-by-someone-other-than-me-and) for an example of how to do that in TFS. I imagine you're using something other than TFS if you're working in Java, but there should be equivalent functionality there too. At one of my previous companies we used this to make sure that subcomponent architects were aware of any changes to Code they "owned" - in theory, people were supposed to have the subcomponent architect code review all changes that impacted their subcomponent, but people sometimes forgot, so this helped us enforce that rule. You may want to do something similar (have a rule that you must code review all changes to Code that you "own").

Even if you *could* absolutely prevent other people from modifying your class, I don't recommend it because the odds of never needing to modify a class at all over the entire product lifecycle is actually relatively low.

As indicated in other answers/comments, the closest you can get in Java to this is by using the `final` framework, which'll prevent the class from being subclassed any further.

You *could* also make the class's *data* immutable (i.e. The publicly-available data never changes), but I don't think that that's exactly what you're looking to do either.

Short answer: you can't do this from code and you probably wouldn't want to.